# BeautifulSoup: Extracting string between tags does not seem to work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently parsing this [url](https://www.kith.com/sitemap_products_1.xml). the Url will be the argument for the parse function.

```
def parse(sitemap):
req = urllib.request.urlopen(sitemap)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')
soup.prettify()
inventory_url = []
inventory_url_set = set()

for item in soup.find_all('url'):
    print(item.find('lastmod'))

    # print(item.find('lastmod').text)
    inventory_url_set.add(item.find('loc').text)
```

However, `item.find('lastmod').text` retuns an AttributeError whereas if I were to print the whole tag `item.find('lastmod')` it works fine.

I'd like to only obtain the text in between the 'lastmod' tag from within each 'item'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all of the `url` entries contain a `lastmod`, so you need to test for that. If you use a dictionary, you could store the `lastmod` as values and still benefit from having unique URLs as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import urllib.request

def parse(sitemap):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(sitemap)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')
    inventory_urls = {}

    for url in soup.find_all('url'):
        if url.lastmod:
            lastmod = url.lastmod.text
        else:
            lastmod = None

        inventory_urls[url.loc.text] = lastmod

    for url, lastmod in inventory_urls.items():
        print(lastmod, url)

parse("https://www.kith.com/sitemap_products_1.xml")
```

This would give you a list starting as follows:

```
2017-02-12T03:55:25Z https://kith.com/products/adidas-originals-stan-smith-wool-pk-grey-white
2017-03-13T18:55:24Z https://kith.com/products/norse-projects-niels-pocket-boucle-tee-black
2017-03-15T17:20:47Z https://kith.com/products/ronnie-fieg-x-fracap-rf120-rust
2017-03-17T01:30:25Z https://kith.com/products/new-balance-696-birch
2017-01-23T08:43:56Z https://kith.com/products/ronnie-fieg-x-diamond-supply-co-x-asics-gel-lyte-v-1
2017-03-17T00:41:03Z https://kith.com/products/off-white-diagonal-ferns-hoodie-black
2017-03-16T15:01:55Z https://kith.com/products/norse-projects-skagen-bubble-crewneck-charcoal
2017-02-21T15:57:56Z https://kith.com/products/vasque-eriksson-gtx-brown-black
```